# Pop() method always giving the first element from stack without erasing it

Tags: c, tree, stack, expression

My program is supposed to read a postfix expression and convert it to infix and prefix using a tree implementation. 
the **pop()** method always give the first element without errasing it and i can't figure out why. Any help will be apreciate.

```
        //tree structur
        typedef struct asa {
          enum {  number_exp,sous_exp_op } type;
          union {
                  int                                    child;
                  struct {
                           struct asa*      left;
                           struct asa*      right;
                           char              oper; }       tree;
              } op;
        } asa;

        //stack
        typedef struct stack {
            int size;

                struct {
                  asa *  element;
                  struct stack* link;
                }e;

        } stack;

        struct stack *top;

        (...)

       asa * pop(){
        asa* e ;
        stack * temp;
        if(top->size == 0 ){
            printf("ERR0R : empty stack\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (top->size >= 1){
            temp = top->e.link;
            e= top->e.element;

            top = temp;
        }
        return e;
    }

void push(asa* node ){
    if(top->size == 0 ){
        top->e.element = node;
        top->e.link = NULL;
        top->size++;
    }
    else if (top->size > 0){
        pile * next = (pile*) malloc(sizeof(top));
        next = top;
        top->e.element = node;
        top->e.link = next;
        top->size++;
    }
}
```

Logs snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Pop looks fine. Maybe post your push too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problems are that you are discarding `next` as soon as you allocate it when `top->size > 0` and that you are allocating the size for a pointer rather than for the whole struct. To fix them, replace `next = top` with `top = next` at the end of the function and fix the `sizeof` invocation:

```
    else if (top->size > 0){
        pile * next = (pile*) malloc(sizeof(*top));
        next->e.element = node;
        next->e.link = top;
        next->size = top->size + 1;
        top = next;
    }
```

Also, this implementation of stack feels needlessly complex and error-prone. If you need the stack size, you should maintain the size independently of the nodes of the linked list, not in every individual node. The standard linked list idiom is to represent the empty list (stack) as NULL, so neither push nor pop need any extra code to check for empty stack:

```
typedef struct stack {
    asa *element;
    struct stack *next;
} stack;

void push(stack **head, asa *elem)
{
  stack *new_head = malloc(sizeof(stack));
  new_head->next = head;
  new_head->elem = elem;
  *head = new_head;
}

asa *pop(stack **head)
{
  stack *old_head = *head;
  asa *top_elem = old_head->elem;
  *head = old_head->next;
  free(old_head);
  return top_elem;
}
```